# Shell script - search for a line and display line and 3 trailing lines

Tags: shell, awk, grep

I'm writing a script that will search for a query and when found it will display that line plus 3 trailing lines. I've no problem finding that line and displaying it but the trailing lines are causing problems.

After looking into it - I don't have the version of `grep`  needed to use -A -B for following lines.

```
_findError()
{
SEARCH=$1
echo $SEARCH

if [ `grep -c "$SEARCH" "$FILE" 2>/dev/null` -gt 0 ]; then
while read LINE
        do
             if [ `echo "$LINE" | grep -c "$SEARCH"` -gt 0 ]; then
                echo "$LINE" >> $FILE
            fi
        done < $FILE        
else
echo "not found"
fi


}
```

I am wondering how I would go about writing the trailing lines to the txt file?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please show a [mcve] so that we can approach the problem not through your snippet but through any other possible tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With GNU and Solaris' sed:

```
SEARCH="^root"
sed -n '/'"$SEARCH"'/{N;N;N;p;}' /etc/passwd
```

Output:

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
daemon:x:1:1:daemon:/usr/sbin:/bin/sh
bin:x:2:2:bin:/bin:/bin/sh
sys:x:3:3:sys:/dev:/bin/sh
```

Comment: Beware this fails if the SEARCH hits within 3 lines of the end-of-file. (No output.)

Comment: With the file I'm using - this shouldn't be an issue. Is there a way to retrieve the two lines above also?

Comment: @JeffY: right. To fix this replace `{N;N;N;p;}` by `{p;n;p;n;p;n;p;}`.

Comment: Found this resolution on another forum and seems to be working perfect - `echo | nawk '$0~s{for(c=NR-b;c<=NR+a;c++)r[c]=1}{q[NR]=$0}END{for(c=1;c<=NR;c++)if(r[c])print q[c]}' b=4 a=3 s="$SEARCHTERM" "$INPUTFILE" >>$OUPUTFILE` b = the number of lines before searchterm and a = number of lines after.

Answer (score 0):

gawk

```
seq 10 | awk '/6/{a=4}a-->0'
6
7
8
9
```

Comment: I wonder how can this answer can be useful without any kind of explanation. You may want to read [answer] to provide better quality answers, since many of them seem to be one-liners without anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Ouch, you're invoking `grep` on each line individually? Don't. Instead:

```
awk '/'"$SEARCH"'/{n=NR}NR==n+4{n=0;print ""}n'
```

To additionally print (up to) "two lines before", as asked in a comment:

```
awk '/'"$SEARCH"'/{if(!n){print prev2;print prev1}n=NR}
     NR==n+4{n=0;print ""}
     {prev2=prev1;prev1=$0}
     n'
```